# VueJs add non-reactive prop from parent to custom component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I’m trying to figure out how to use the reactivity system economically. I understand that $options for a component are for non-reactive data and are typically set in a created() or mounted() method from within itself. But is there a way to pass in non-reactive props on init from the parent?

For a simple example:

- let’s say I have a component that renders a value as currency.
- 99% of the time currency will be USD and
- 100% of the time currency will not change after instantiation.
- But the value needs to be reactive.
  (this is a dumbed down example just to demonstrate the concept)

```
props: {
    value: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    currency: {
        type: String,
        default: 'USD',
    },
},
```

But I don’t want to spend a watcher on currency, since it will never change.

Can I somehow pass it in as an unwatched $option? Is there another way of doing this? Or are watchers so cheap I shouldn't worry about efficiency at scale?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Vue is heavily optimized to make reactivity fast and scalable, so my initial reaction is that you are making a premature optimization. I'd recommend trying it and seeing if you have any rendering issues.

Comment: Thanks, this is good feedback and addresses my question. I'm trying to avoid patching up leaks when the app scales large, but maybe I'm being too cautious given the framework. I'm still curious in theory how you would do it if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

To get a non-reactive field, use a regular HTML attribute instead of a declared property, and access it via the component `$attrs` object.

I would go with the `Vue` `property` though.  It is typesafe, validated, and the overhead is insignificant.

```html
<my-element currency='12' />
```

```js
const currency = parseFloat(this.$attrs.currency)
```

Comment: Hey Steven - This is super close to what I'm looking for. Can the currency= a js variable? Like i want it to be dynamic on init, but then not a watcher. So I'd like to put currencyVariable into the currency attribute.

Comment: put it in `created` or `mounted`.  use `this.currency` and add `currency` to `data`.